# Sum of promise values and return promise JS

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, task

I have a task to create a function **summarize1** that receives promises and returns promise with sum of their values as shown below:

```
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(4);
const promise2 = new Promise((resolve) => resolve(2));
summarize1(promise1, promise2).then((sum) => {console.log(sum);}); // result: 6
```

With this test implementation:

```
describe('summarize1', () => {
    it('should return 9 for given promises', async () => {
        const promise1 = Promise.resolve(9);
        const res = await summarize1(promise1);
        assert.strictEqual(res, 9);
    });

    it('should return 6 for given promises', async () => {
        const promise1 = Promise.resolve(2);
        const promise2 = Promise.resolve(4);
        const res = await summarize1(promise1, promise2);
        assert.strictEqual(res, 6);
    });

    it('should return 11 for given promises', async () => {
        const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
        const promise2 = new Promise(resolve => resolve(9));
        const res = await summarize1(promise1, promise2);
        assert.strictEqual(res, 12);
    });

    it('should return 16 for given promises', async () => {
        const promise1 = Promise.resolve(10);
        const promise2 = new Promise(resolve => resolve(5));
        const promise3 = new Promise(resolve => {setTimeout(() => {resolve(1)}, 300)});
        const res = await summarize1(promise1, promise2, promise3);
        assert.strictEqual(res, 16);
    });
});
```

And an **async function** called **summarize2** that receives promises and returns promise with sum of their values as shown above in summarize1.
With this test:

```
describe('summarize2', () => {
    it('should return 9 for given promises', async () => {
        const promise1 = Promise.resolve(9);
        const res = await summarize2(promise1);
        assert.strictEqual(res, 9);
    });

    it('should return 6 for given promises', async () => {
        const promise1 = Promise.resolve(2);
        const promise2 = Promise.resolve(4);
        const res = await summarize2(promise1, promise2);
        assert.strictEqual(res, 6);
    });

    it('should return 11 for given promises', async () => {
        const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
        const promise2 = new Promise(resolve => resolve(9));
        const res = await summarize2(promise1, promise2);
        assert.strictEqual(res, 12);
    });

    it('should return 16 for given promises', async () => {
        const promise1 = Promise.resolve(10);
        const promise2 = new Promise(resolve => resolve(5));
        const promise3 = new Promise(resolve => {setTimeout(() => {resolve(1)}, 300)});
        const res = await summarize2(promise1, promise2, promise3);
        assert.strictEqual(res, 16);
    });

    it('should return 23 for given promises', async () => {
        const promise1 = Promise.resolve(11);
        const promise2 = new Promise(resolve => resolve(7));
        const promise3 = new Promise(resolve => {setTimeout(() => {resolve(5)}, 500)});
        const res = await summarize2(promise1, promise2, promise3);
        assert.strictEqual(res, 23);
    });

    it('should return 16 for given promises', async () => {
        const promise1 = new Promise(resolve => {setTimeout(() => {resolve(1)}, 500)});
        const promise2 = new Promise(resolve => {setTimeout(() => {resolve(3)}, 500)});
        const promise3 = new Promise(resolve => {setTimeout(() => {resolve(5)}, 500)});
        const promise4 = new Promise(resolve => {setTimeout(() => {resolve(7)}, 500)});
        const res = await summarize2(promise1, promise2, promise3, promise4);
        assert.strictEqual(res, 16);
    });

    it('should return 42 for given promises', async () => {
        const promise1 = Promise.resolve(21);
        const promise2 = Promise.resolve(21);
        const res = await summarize2(promise1, promise2);
        assert.strictEqual(res, 42);
    });
});
```

The problem is that i dont understand how to implement this task to satisfy the condition,to be able to create as many promises we want and then just to get the sum of their values from resolve.

I had 4 tries,and nothing works,i dont know what to do anymore,i searched every documentation,every refference,and nothing about what i need. PS: im new to JS

This is my first try:

```
    new Promise((resolve) => resolve(value));
    function sum(value){
     return new Promise((resolve)=>{
    resolve(value+value);
    });
    }
```

Second try:

```
async function getFirstPromise(){
   
        return new Promise((resolve)=>resolve(value1));
    }
    async function getSecondPromise(){
    
        return new Promise((resolve)=>resolve(value2));
    }
   
    const sum = new Promise((resolve)=>{
        var promise1 = await getFirstPromise();
        var promise2 = await getSecondPromise();
        resolve(promise1+promise2);
    })
    return sum.then(function(sum){
        console.log(sum);
    });
```

Third try:

```
const promise1 = new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(value);
        }, 1000);
    });
    const promise2 = new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(value);
        }, 1000);
    });
    const sum = new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(promise1 + promise2);
        }, 1000);
        
    });
    sum.then(function () {
        return sum;
    });
```

And last:

```
   let promise1;
    let promise2;
    let sum = new Promise((resolve)=>{
resolve(sum);
    });
    sum.then((value)=>{
        return value;
    })
```

Maybe somewhere i go on the right path,but because of the lack of experience,i dont know what i should do and what to expect.Please help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a few key parts that JavaScript can do

1. Take variable number of arguments in a function using [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)
2. Wait for multiple promises to resolve and then do something, using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```js
const summarize1 = (...promises) => {
  return Promise.all(promises).then(nums => {
    let sum = 0;
    for (const num of nums) {
      sum += num;
    }
    return sum;
  })
}

const promise1 = Promise.resolve(4);
const promise2 = new Promise((resolve) => resolve(2));
summarize1(promise1, promise2).then((sum) => {
  console.log(sum);
});
```

Since you've mentioned you're new to JS, I didn't use anything more than necessary to explain the solution above. But, there's a utility function on arrays, called `reduce`, that can be used instead of the for loop above

```js
const summarize1 = (...promises) => {
  return Promise.all(promises).then(nums => nums.reduce((sum, ele) => sum + ele));
}

const promise1 = Promise.resolve(4);
const promise2 = new Promise((resolve) => resolve(2));
summarize1(promise1, promise2).then((sum) => {
  console.log(sum);
});
```

Comment: For even shorter code, consider using `reduce` for summing. It's pretty much the textbook example of how to use reducers.

Comment: @JHH Yes, agreed! Wanted to give a simpler example first to the OP. Then introduce `reduce` as another way to do the same thing.

Comment: Very good ansewer,thank you,but there is a little detail,how to give to Promise.resolve(4) not to be a 4 but an input number,cause in the test there are different values,and it can not pass it if there is a constant. And to promise to also

Comment: @NerdyStudent I don't know what you mean. The function will receive promises and sum up their values. Can you share an example of your "little detail"?

Comment: Oh,nvm,i had a moment of stupidity for myself :)) i thought that promise1 and promise2 in the code above is part of the function,but it was for the demonstrating the algorithm :))

Comment: Everything works good,the task is passed,thank you for help.I didnt have the idea of such an implementation and i would have lost a lot of time in vain.I have a lot to study,but everything has a start.